# What does ./ do for a source in html?

Tags: php, html

Reading through some code I recently was signed on to (I'm an intern).
I'm supposed to change out some logos and links.
Problem is that none of the images show because they all have **./images** instead of **../images**.
What is **./** used for? I really don't feel like changing everything to **../** .
The files are set up like this **Main.php**, two folders one is images other is includes.
Includes contains other php files that contain links to the images using the **./** but don't work.
How would I fix this problem?

Comment: http://linuxtutorial.info/modules.php?name=MContent&pageid=17

Comment: See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)

Comment: You wouldn't want to arbitrarily change all `./` into `../`... that's a whole different directory path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're called relative directory paths.

`./` represents the same directory as the HTML file. `../` represents one directory up the tree.